# How to go back from Safari to UIWebView (iphone)

Tags: iphone

I really want to thank you all you guys first , I began  iOS programming learning  several weeks ago ,and I have  learnt a lot from here these days,.

I have a UIWebView and loading some html content with "loadHTMLString" method, when i click hyperlinks in the UIwebView, It comforms the

```
-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request 
 navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType{ 
     if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked) {
          [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[Request URL]];
          return NO;
     }
     return YES;
 }
```

to open a Safari.

My question is: Can I go back from the Safari to the UIWebView? how?

Answer (score 0):

You can't get Safari to send the user back whenever you want, but one way to get back to your application is by creating a custom URL scheme (e.g. `myapp://return`, or whatever scheme makes sense to you), assuming that the web page the person is going to can have links that are intended to go back to your appliaction.

You can do this by registering that your application handles the URL scheme, and then processing the request appropriately when iOS tells you to. The [Apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/StandardBehaviors/StandardBehaviors.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW50) are fairly complete about this.

But if you want your application to be able to arbitrarily pull people back whenever you want, I don't think that's possible. Safari isn't under the control of anyone but Apple.

Comment: thank you very much !!

when click hyperlinks in the UIWebView, how about pushing a new ViewController whose view is a UIWebView and whose main function is to simulate a web browser?   compared with creating a custom URL scheme.

Comment: Sure, you could do this. You won't get all of Safari's features, but you can certainly make your own miniature browser there.